# Approximation error of Chebyshev expansion of the second kind

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory, analytic-functions

Weierstrass' well known theorem states that every continuous function on $[-1,1]$ can be uniformly approximated to arbitrary precision by a polynomial function.  Among these approximations it is known the Chebyshev polynomials are such "best approximations".  In quatitive terms, it is known for exmaple (see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904587900657) that if a function $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ is $M$ times continuously differentiable then the $M$-truncated Chebyshev approximation of $f$, i.e.:
$$
f^M(x) = \sum_{k=0}^M \alpha_k T_k(x),
\quad
\alpha_k = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{-1}^1 f(x) T_k(x) / \sqrt{1-x^2} dx
$$
is a minimax approximation of $f$ and we have:
$$
\left\| f - f^M \right\| = \frac{V}{2^M (M+1)!},
\quad
V = \max_{x\in [-1,1]} \left| f^{(M)}(x) \right|
$$
where the LHS norm is the maximal absolute value difference on $[-1,1]$.

Other results exist for other classes of functions.  Yet, the literature hardly relates to Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.  Does every quantitive theorem on the approximation error of first-kind Chebyshev approximation carry over to the second kind?

Formally, what is known about the similar expansion of the second kind? i.e.
$$
f^M(x) = \sum_{k=0}^M \alpha_k U_k(x),
\quad
\alpha_k = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{-1}^1 f(x) U_k(x) \sqrt{1-x^2} dx
$$
where $U_k(x)$ is defined by $U_k(\cos(t)) = \sin((k+1) t) / \sin(t)$